# How do I move all recent photos from iPhone to PC, but keep my favourites on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos

I regularly plug my iPhone into my Windows PC and 'Import photos and videos', and then delete them from the device, which is what I want.

But how can I select a few 'favourite' photos and keep those on the iPhone, without them getting removed when I do regular transfers to the PC of all my *new* photos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using iTunes for syncing your phone, take a look at this article:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4236?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

It describes how you can sync photos from your PC to your iPhone.   So, if (for example) you keep a folder on your PC called *Favorite Photos*, and have that folder selected to sync to your phone, it will always copy those photos to your phone, even after you remove all the pictures during an upload.