# Why aren't iTunes and Windows Photo acknowledging my iPhone?

Tags: iphone

My mom must move pictures on her iPhone (not iCloud) to her PC. She's computer-illiterate, and I'm using TeamViewer to access her PC. She has plugged in her iPhone to her PC. Then her iPhone asked her "Trust This Computer?", and she obviously clicked "Trust".

[This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114003) links to [an Apple website dated Oct 28 2018](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4236?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) that features an ostensibly outdated iTunes layout because it differs from the one below, and I downloaded iTunes today.

[This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/308134) recommends the Window Photos App.

[image]

Comment: Do you get any prompt on the iOS device? Does it say device/accessory not supported?

Comment: You must unlock the iPhone in order to get data connection to any device at all, on recent iOS. Re-connect, enter touchID or passcode.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think she did? Please see my edited post.

Comment: @abc Yes, but not "device/accessory not supported". Please see my edited post.